# Enable CORS in Starcounter

Tags: c#, starcounter

I am trying to send a browser request to my Starcounter app from a script in a website on another host. I get an error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at . This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS

What is the best way to enable CORS in a Starcounter app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to accept requests from other hosts in a web browser, you need to implement CORS. This is done the same way in Starcounter as in most other application frameworks.

To accept `GET` requests or simple `POST` requests (with standard headers) from any host, you only need to add a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your HTTP GET handlers. For example:

```
Handle.GET("/myapp/some-page", () => {
  var page = new Json();
  var response = new Response();
  response.Resource = page;
  response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  return response;
});
```

To accept all requests that change something on the server (`POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`), you should implement an `OPTIONS` preflight request handler to the same URI at your `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` handler. For example:

```
Handle.PUT("/myapp/some-page", () => {
  var page = new Json();
  /* some logic ... */
  var response = new Response();
  response.Resource = page;
  response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  return response;
});

Handle.OPTIONS("/myapp/some-page", () => {
  var response = new Response();
  response.Resource = page;
  response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS";
  response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*";
  return response;
});
```

Read more about CORS at:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: `Handle.AddOutgoingHeader("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");` can be used to set headers If the response object is not available,